# Error: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend after changing from hardcoded data to process.env

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, backend

I got this error:

**@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.9.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times.**

after chaning my firebase config from

```
  apiKey: "SecretApiKey",
  authDomain: "SecretAuthDomain",
  [...]
}
```

**to:**

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.apiKey,
  authDomain: process.env.authDomain,
  [...]
}
```

also I didnt get this error like 2 days ago or when i was making other project with firebase.

I saw that problem on internet and solution was to change to this:

```
const firestoreDB = initializeFirestore(firebaseApp, {
  experimentalForceLongPolling: true, // this line
  useFetchStreams: false, // and this line
})
```

**but this doesnt work also for me and i get another error.**

Answer (score 0):

I had credentials setup in .env file which did show up as appropriate variables. However, What worked for me was putting the credentials in a `.js` file and use them from there.
Also, please do not forget to add the credentials file in `.gitignore`